# Excel - Nested waterfall plot

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

Is it possible to create a nested waterfall chart in Excel, having an aggregator below Jan-Feb-March that says *winter*, one for *spring* below April, May, June and so on so forth.

[image: Chart Waterfall example]

The image is just an example of a waterfall. I am using Excel 2016 and can create the waterfall plot. What I want is to have a sort of a grouping label underneath some of the elements of the waterfall. The equivalent of what I would like using the shown waterfall plot would be to have a label underneath Jan, Feb, Mar specifying that they are part of *winter*, one under Apr, May, Jun specifying that they are part of *spring* and so on.

Comment: Are you asking how to create this type of chart, how to add season labels below the months, how to aggregate the data and chart it by season, or something else?  The question isn't clear.

Comment: Are you using the built-in Excel Waterfall chart that was introduced with Excel 2016? Your sample chart colours look like you are using an older version of Excel. The answers will vary depending on your version.

Comment: What is the data source? Could you provide more information?

Comment: That image was just an example of a waterfall. I am using excel 2016 and can create the waterfall plot, what i want is to have a sort of a grouping label underneath some of the elements of the waterfall. The equivalent of what I would like using the shown waterfall plot would be to have a label underneath Jan, Feb, Mar specifying that they are part of winter, one under apr may June specifying that they are part of spring and so on. Is this more clear?

Comment: Insert text boxes underneath?

Comment: This is a great question, and a nice improvement option for Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Approach 1. Following my tutorial [Excel Waterfall Charts (Bridge Charts)](https://peltiertech.com/excel-waterfall-charts-bridge-charts/), I set up the data below. It is the same as in the tutorial with the exception of the first column which contains labels for the seasons and blank cells elsewhere (the blue shaded cells are completely empty). Formulas are the same as in the tutorial. I selected the shaded range (yellow and blue cells), selecting the first area, then holding Ctrl while selecting the second area, so that both areas were selected. I then inserted a stacked column chart (top chart), and formatted per the tutorial to get my waterfall (bottom chart). Excel uses both columns for the labels, giving the nested appearance.

[image: Nested Waterfall Chart 1]

Approach 2. Using a commercial Excel add-in, I used the data in columns C and D above to create a waterfall chart. I selected the first series in the waterfall chart, and modified the X values to include not just column C but both columns B and C for the axis labels.

[image: Nested Waterfall Chart 2]

The native Excel waterfall chart cannot use two columns for X axis labels, so it can't provide category grouping like either of these.

Approach 3. Although it doesn't really nest the months together, this approach divides the chart into quarters by placing a subtotal between groups of three months. There are rows inserted into the data to provide for these calculated subtotals. This was also created using the commercial Excel add-in, but it could have been done manually or with the native Excel waterfall.

[image: Nested Waterfall Chart 3]

I'm not marketing here (no link), just noting for the record that the commercial Excel add-in that I used to generate the waterfall charts is my own product, Peltier Tech Charts for Excel.

Comment: Jon, it's been awhile since I spotted one of your answers.  I was going through withdrawal.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do that kind of labeling is to use the axis title (which isn't being used in the illustration).  Type the season labels as the axis title and insert spaces between them (and at one end if necessary), to accomplish the required positioning.  You can adjust the title font as desired (do that before tweaking the positioning).  If you need the axis title as an axis title, use a text box (or multiple text boxes), for the season labels.

Comment: Is it possible to have it change it dynamically. E.g. :

DATA
START VALUE                     1000
                     micro 1              -10
MACRO 1     micro 2                10
                     micro 3              -10

                     micro 1              10
MACRO 2     micro 2                -10
                     micro 3              10

FINAL VALUE                       1000

The changes I have in name in Micro1 are reflected into the table

Comment: @user1012511, I did a Google search on "excel chart use cell reference in titles", and there are a lot of links for how to do it.  But according to Microsoft (see [this link](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/link-a-chart-title-label-or-text-box-to-a-worksheet-cell-efc8173a-2a8a-423b-b4e2-b10c62fca6f5)), waterfall charts are among the chart types for which there is no native support to link the content of titles, labels or text boxes to cell contents.  I'm not familiar with a workaround for waterfall charts, but maybe another reader will have a suggestion.